# master details entities, aggregate root - Abp Core

Tags: entity-framework, aspnetboilerplate

what is the best way to create parent-child entities

e.g

```
 oreder-->details
 recipe-->ingredients
 car-->parts
```

the doc talks about "Agregate root" https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Entities#aggregateroot-class

Is there any example? does exist another way? any suggestion please?

isn't this enough?
**order entity:**

```
....
...
..
[ForeignKey("OrderId")]
public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; }
....
...
```

Comment: You can implement something like this
[Table("Child")]
public class ChildClass : FullAuditedEntity
{
 [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
 public ParentClass ParentClass { get; set; }
}

Comment: @viveknuna nothing different from normal entity framework, is it correct?

Comment: yes, I have implemented the same in my project. I have the same relationship the only difference is that in your case, the parent has more than one child, but in my case parent has only one child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's it!

```cs
public class Order : FullAuditedEntity
{
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail : FullAuditedEntity
{
    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```